# Cannot call prototype method from another function

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, prototype

{EDIT} Actual code here: http://jsfiddle.net/r79xtbdm/

I have a constructor function as follows (pseudo-code):

```
function Tile(<pass in arguments here>)
     {
        // set some variables here based on arguments passed (this.width, this.height) etc..
     }
```

Outside of this constructor function, I use prototype to provide a method for the function as follows:

```
Tile.prototype.draw = function() {
        // do some stuff 
     }
```

I have another function as follows:

```
function createTileMap()
        {
            var firstTile = new Tile(<arguments>);
            firstTile.draw();
        }
```

The issue I am having is that the firstTile object is being created (I can access it's properties). However, firstTile.draw raises an undefined function error. I assume this is a  matter of scope but can't get my head around it. Why can the createTileMap function not see the prototype method that has been added to the tile constructor?

Thanks! Have been banging my head against a wall for a few hours with this.

Comment: You need to show the code that has the error. Above is 100% fine.

Comment: Something else is wrong because [your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/eymx5c07/)

Comment: Okay, i'll post something to JSFiddle.

Comment: Here is the relevant JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r79xtbdm/.

Comment: createTileMap is called before the draw function is assigned to the prototype. If you move the calls after it is set, it should work fine. (http://jsfiddle.net/r79xtbdm/1/ )

Comment: Thanks @Me.Name - that was it. This is why interpreted languages get on my wick. Having to declare things in a certain order. :)

Comment: @Me.Name Please add this as a solution in order this issue to be marked as solved. Otherwise, the solution may be not even read.